# Simplest way to add cookies to jQuery toogle

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggle, toggleclass

This is my first post on stackoverflow :) 
I spent whole night to try many ways to do the same thing, but I'm a beginner so I give up and ask for help.

Question was answered many times but I can't find just simple way to make TOGGLE remember current state. I don't want to start my work with jQuery with bloated code.

I need to create just dead simple open/close panel and I found toggle() or toggleClass() will give me what I'm want.

**Final working code from Miro** shortened and fixed by me is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('p').toggleClass('red', $.cookie('currentToggle') === 'on');
    $('button').toggleClass('yellow', $.cookie('currentToggle') === 'on');
});

$("button").click(function () {
    $("p").toggleClass("red");
    $(this).toggleClass("yellow");
    $.cookie('currentToggle', $("p").hasClass('red') ? 'on' : 'off');
});
```

Thanks Miro!

Comment: on click of the toggle set the cookie to that value. then on document ready check to see what state (class) the cookie is at and add the appropriate class to the relevent selector. Its pretty easy

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I tried many ways, but I want all of it it short.

Miro add great solution but there is something wrong. You can see in my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('p').toggleClass('red', $.cookie('currentToggle') === 'on');  
});
$(function(){

    $("button").click(function () {
        $("p").toggleClass("red");
        $(this).toggleClass("yellow");      
        $.cookie('currentToggle', $("p").hasClass('red')?'on':'off' );
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, I'll found BUG! 
Should be : instead of ,

$.cookie('currentToggle', $("p").hasClass('red')?'on':'off' );